# Tensorflow: How to randomly select elements according to condition without np.where?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I have 3 tensorflow arrays (`a`, `b`, `valid_entries`), which share the first two dimensionalities `[T, N, ?]`. One of these arrays 'valid_entries' has shape `[T,N,1]` with boolean values. I want to randomly sample `T*M` 2-tuples of indices (`M < N`) such that `valid_entries[t,m] == 1` for all of these indices.

In other words, for each time step, I want to randomly select M valid entries from `a` and `b`.

I persume that in numpy, this task would be solved by doing the following (let's skip the first dimension T for simplicity):

```
M = 3
N = 5
valid_entries = [[0],[1],[0],[1],[0]]
valid_indices = np.where(a==1)
valid_indices = np.random.select(valid_indices,np.min(len(valid_indices),M))
a_new = a[valid_indices]
b_new = b[valid_indices]
valid_new = valid_entries[valid_indices]
```

However, all this needs to happen in Tensorflow.

Thanks a ton in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that does that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def sample_indices(valid, m, seed=None):
    valid = tf.convert_to_tensor(valid)
    n = tf.size(valid)
    # Flatten boolean tensor
    valid_flat = tf.reshape(valid, [n])
    # Get flat indices where the tensor is true
    valid_idx = tf.boolean_mask(tf.range(n), valid_flat)
    # Shuffled valid indices
    valid_idx_shuffled = tf.random.shuffle(valid_idx, seed=seed)
    # Pick sample from shuffled indices
    valid_idx_sample = valid_idx_shuffled[:m]
    # Unravel indices
    return tf.transpose(tf.unravel_index(valid_idx_sample, tf.shape(valid)))

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    valid = [[ True,  True, False,  True],
             [False,  True,  True, False],
             [False,  True, False, False]]
    m = 4
    print(sess.run(sample_indices(valid, m, seed=0)))
    # [[1 1]
    #  [1 2]
    #  [0 1]
    #  [2 1]]
```

This `sample_indices` is generic for any shape of boolean tensor. If in your case `valid_entries` has shape `(T, N, 1)` then you will get a tensor with shape `(M, 3)` as output, although you can ignore the last column since it is always going to be zero (or you can pass `tf.squeeze(valid_entries, axis=2)` instead).

Note: The last `tf.transpose` is just to have as output a tensor with shape `(sample_size, num_dimensions)` instead of the other way around. However, if `m` is rather big and you don't mind the order of the dimensions, you may skip it to save a bit of time and memory, since (unlike its NumPy counterpart) `tf.transpose` produces a whole new tensor.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

FYI, I then used `tf.gather` for indexing/slicing with a list of indices.